# Text alignment in a minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I have a little problematic in LaTeX, and I have not found any solution.

I have a minipage like this :

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    {\bfseries Some text}\\[.35ex]
    \small
    Text again\\
    And again\\\[.35ex]
\end{minipage}
```

This code permit me to put my minipage in the right of my page, but the text in the minipage have a right alignment, and I need it left center (no center in the page but center in the minipage).

So, if someone had a solution... Maybe use a minipage is not the right solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, but it's not clear what you want; can you help more?

Comment: Since your minipage as width `\textwidth`, any alignment will be relative to that. Do you want a `minipage` that has centred content but is flush right with the page?

Comment: I want a minipage, in the right of my document. And the text in my minipage with a left alignment.

Comment: in the absence of a minimal example, i suggest this as one possibility:  `\begingroup \noindent\hfil`<the minipage>`\parfillskip0pt\par\endgroup`.  forget about the `\raggedleft`.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in several ways; below I include two options; the first one, using a `minipage` and the second one, a `tabular` with one `l` column (in case that the contents is required to wrap, a `p{<length>}` column should be used instead); showframe was only used to draw a frame as visual guideline for the alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

%Using a minipage:
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{2.6cm}
    {\bfseries Some test text} \\[.35ex]
    \small
    Text again \\
    And again
\end{minipage}

%Using a tabular:
\hfill\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    {\bfseries Some test text} \\[.35ex]
    \small
    Text again \\
    And again
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]